# How to navigate to a subdomain without specifying the domain? (in a web browser)

Tags: macos, dns, bind

I want to be able to navigate to my home network's web server from my browser without having to type in any domain or top level domain. For example, I want to type:

```
http://mylinuxbox/
```

and have it navigate to

```
http://mylinuxbox.mylocaldomain.tld/
```

I've been able to configure bind to get the qualified host name to navigate correctly, but I'm not sure how to get the unqualified one to work. I know it's possible because I've seen academic and corporate networks allow you to easily navigate to their internal websites this way.

How can I achieve this using `bind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your client computer with a [primary DNS suffix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7NNl.jpg) and/or set [DNS search suffixes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZGWA.jpg) in your TCP/IP settings.

Comment: hmmmm, i need to figure out how to do this on Mac OS X

Comment: Try [Editing DNS and search domain settings](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph6373?locale=en_GB)